# FindQt4 in CMake not recognize flag -m32

Tags: qt, gcc, cmake

I try to build x86 application on x86_64 platform (Fedora16). In this application I'm using Qt and build system is cmake.
In CMakeLists.txt I'm using:

`find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED qtmain QtCore QtGui QtWebKit)`

`include(${QT_USE_FILE})`

cmake command for generate Makefile like this:

`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fpermissive -m32"
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINKER_PREFERENCE="-m32"
-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-m32"
-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-m32"`

So, after compiling linker cannot find compatible Qt library. Error like this:

`/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libQtWebKit.so when searching for -lQtWebKit`

It's ok. In /usr/lib64 library has x64 platform. Desired library in /usr/lib, and they exist! But I don't understand, why FindQt4 not recognize platform? This script set following variable: QT_LIBRARY_DIR, QT_LIBRARIES and so one. Such variables set to following:

`-- QT_LIBRARY_DIR: /usr/lib64`

`-- QT_LIBRARIES: optimized;/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit_debug.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libQtXmlPatterns.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libQtXmlPatterns_debug.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libQtGui.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libQtGui_debug.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork_debug.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libQtCore_debug.so`

My question: why not /usr/lib? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because FindQt4 module knows nothing about `-m32` flag.

Try to set `QT_LIBRARY_DIR` explicitly.

Comment: I've already tried it. I've done it firstly, but nothing =( In FindQt4 script there is nothing like CMAKE_SIZE_OF_VOID_P

Comment: Documentation says that FindQt4 uses `qmake` program from `PATH` env var to detect everything else. Maybe you have separate `qmake` for 32-bit and 64-bit Qt? If not, i fear there is nothing you can do except setting `QT_LIBRARIES` manually. Well, you can manually replace `lib64` with `lib` in libraries paths.

Comment: thanx a lot for advise! I've made patch - replace lib64 to lib (in the variable `QT_LIBRARIES`). But I think, it's not good. So, everybody knows that there is nothing more infinite then temporary =)